# Portable way to check if a path is absolute or relative in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a new Makefile insfrastructure, which I've managed so far to make very portable in the sense that it works (with GNU-make):

- on Linux
- on Windows (only with CMD shell + GnuWin32 CoreUtils + GnuWin32 Make)
- on Windows (with MSYS2 shell)

I am using canned recipes, and the recipes use arguments provided from the top. These arguments are typically header include dirs and library include dirs.

So far I've assumed that all the paths provided to the canned recipes are relative to where the Makefile resides - Within the recipes, these paths always prefixed with:

```
ROOT_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Very recently, I've come across an example where the include path that I need to specify is not simple to specify in relative terms.
If coreutils "realpath --relative-to" was working on Windows I would use it, but it isn't. Also on Windows, relative paths are not always possible anyway e.g. if the include dirs and the makefile are on different drives.

So my preferred approach at the moment would be to detect in the canned recipe if the path provided as argument is absolute or relative. Only if it's relative, it gets prefixed with ROOT_DIR otherwise it's used as is.

Any suggestions how to do this, in a robust and portable way ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will run Make in a working directory that in general is *not* where the makefile resides, is that right?

Comment: Not directly related to the question discussed here, I thought I would share some nice ideas I've found to relate two absolute paths:  

 - [python is portable and provides relpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343828/8543838) - I haven't tried it though, and I wonder how it behaves on Windows when the two absolute paths are not on the same drive... Does it throw an error ?   
 - [getting-relative-links-between-two-paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85060/getting-relative-links-between-two-paths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could check various cases:

1. leading `/`,
2. leading `~`,
3. leading `X:` where `X` is an upper case letter (Windows drive),
4. leading `\\` (Windows network drive)

and for each set a variable to `yes` or the empty string:

```
IS_ROOT    := $(if $(patsubst /%,,$(THE_PATH_TO_CHECK)),,yes)
IS_HOME    := $(if $(patsubst ~%,,$(THE_PATH_TO_CHECK)),,yes)
IS_NETWORK := $(if $(patsubst \\\\%,,$(THE_PATH_TO_CHECK)),,yes)
IS_DRIVE   := $(foreach d,A B C D E...Z,$(if $(patsubst $(d):/%,,$(THE_PATH_TO_CHECK)),,yes))
```

Then, we can test if the concatenation of these variables equals `yes` or not:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(IS_ROOT)$(IS_HOME)$(IS_NETWORK)$(IS_DRIVE)),yes)
<absolute>
else
<relative>
endif
```

Of course, if you have other cases in mind you can add them using similar combinations of make functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start ! Two comments I'd like to make:

Comment: 1) This should almost always work on Linux and on MSYS, except perhaps if the path to check starts with ~. Any suggestions how to deal with this case too ? Are there any other exceptions you can think of ? <br/> 2)
What about the Windows CMD shell case ? How would you check if the path starts with a drive letter ? (my personal habbit is to use forward slahes on Windows too, to avoid any issues) ? The exception in this case might be network paths that start with \\

Comment: I am not using Windows so I cannot test but we could test these cases independently and merge them all with an `ifeq` conditional. See my updated answer.

Comment: it looks like `$(abspath /)` gives the file system's root. I tested it in Msys2 with `mingw32-make` it results in `C:/`. Perhaps it is enough to just check for the prefix given by that.